# Oracle APEX Gantt Chart Axis Date format pattern to display week of year from date

Tags: oracle-apex, gantt-chart

how do I specify in Oracle APEX the date format in the Pattern field so that the calendar week is displayed in a Gantt chart? Screenshots attached.

I have already tried many things (w,ww...). But nothing works. I can't find anything fitting on the internet or in the forum.

Does anyone have an idea?

[Gantt Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4asW4.png) [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLwhY.png)

Answer (score 0):

according to this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4480554/how-to-change-x-axis-format-in-oracle-apex-line-chart) it should be in cldr unicode format, i.e. https://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time/date-time-symbols

trying something complex like `EEEE, MMMM d, y h:mm a` as pattern seems to work.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that I need cldr unicode format. The complex example from you also works so far. But unfortunately I don't get the calendar week. Can it be that this is not supported?